# Lost signing key but i have all other info

Tags: android

due to a disk failure I have lost the signing key of my app.
But I know exactly the alias and password I used.
Two things :
- Can I create a new file with the exact same info and use it to sign my app again?
- If not if there a tool to get the file from the apk (I know the password and alias, no need to crack it)

Many thanks

Comment: Nothing you can do in this case, the apk won't contain the private key so you can't extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Can I create a new file with the exact same info and use it to sign my app again?
> - If not if there a tool to get the file from the apk (I know the password and alias, no need to crack it)

No and no, sorry. You will have to create a new key and deploy the app to Google Play as a new app. Then, make sure you have multiple backups of your signing key.